# What is the equivalent of useRouteMatch for class-based components?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I want to use the `useRouteMatch` hook inside a class-based component in React because it simplifies passing parameter to component. Using this hook inside class component throws error. What is the equivalent of this hook to use in a React class?

Comment: This blog post has before and after examples for the hooks introduced in 5.1: https://reacttraining.com/blog/react-router-v5-1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`useRouteMatch` can be used to match a specific route path or even get the match properties for the currentRoute

For a class component, you could make use of `matchPath` to get the same behaviour

```
import { matchPath } from 'react-router-dom';

class App extends React.Component {
  someFunc = () => {
     const match = matchPath("/users/123", {
        path: "/users/:id",
        exact: true,
       strict: false
     });
     ...
   }
}
```

For a current Route match you can directly get the match values from props if the component is a direct child of Route and rendered as a component. However if it is not, you can either pass on the match props from the parent which is the direct child or use `withRouter` HOC

Please check the [blog post for more details](https://reacttraining.com/blog/react-router-v5-1/)

Answer (score 3):

You could use `withRouter` HOC, and then there will be `match` object in wrapped component props:

```
import React from 'react';
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

class SomeClassComponent extends React.Component {

  render(){
    console.log(this.props.match) // match object
    return(<span />)
  }
}

export default withRouter(SomeClassComponent)
```